# Object formatter using reflection

Tags: java, strings, reinventing-the-wheel, formatting, reflection

I am making an object formatter for use when debugging.

Formatted class:

```
package com.myname.somepackage;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

// Allows a variable to be displayed when using Formatter.format
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Formatted {

}
```

Formatter class:

```
package com.myname.somepackage;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public final class Formatter {
    private Formatter() {}

    // Returns a string containing the object's information, for debugging
    // Format: ClassName[var1=somevalue, var2=somevalue]
    // The object's variables must have the Formatted annotation to be displayed here
    public static String format(Object object) {
        String className = object.getClass().getSimpleName();
        Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        String string = className + "[";
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Formatted annotation = field.getAnnotation(Formatted.class);
            if (annotation != null) {
                String varName = field.getName();
                try {
                    String value = field.get(object).toString();
                    string += varName + "=" + value + ", ";
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    string += varName + "=" + "{Unavailable}, ";
                }
            }
        }
        // remove last ", "
        if (string.endsWith(", "))
            string = string.substring(0, string.length() - 2);
        string += "]";
        return string;
    }
}
```

A class for testing this:

```
package com.myname.somepackage.math.geom.r2;

import com.myname.somepackage.Formatted;
import com.myname.somepackage.Formatter;

public final class Point2d {
    @Formatted
    private final double x, y;

    public Point2d(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    public Point2d setX(double x) {
        return new Point2d(x, this.y);
    }
    public double getY() {
        return this.y;
    }
    public Point2d setY(double y) {
        return new Point2d(this.x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Formatter.format(this);
    }
}
```

The code to test it:

```
Point2d point = new Point2d(4, 2);
System.out.println(point);
```

The console then outputs "`Point2d[x=4.0, y=2.0]`".

How does my code look? I understand reflection is considered bad, but this is just my lazy way of quickly debugging. Thanks

Comment: If the field's value is null, you code will fail with NullPointerException due to unchecked toString() on the get-result.

Comment: I've added the "reinventing-the-wheel" tag because the question and the approach are nice, but... [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) library provides exactly the same functionality out of the box with `@ToString` annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty nice IMO but can be improved.

If your project uses apache commons (this library is often included), you should consider using the `FieldUtils` class to get the fields : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html

Notably, the `getFieldsWithAnnotation` method would reduce your code complexity by a bit.

That's up to you though ;)

This part :

```
try {
    String value = field.get(object).toString();
    string += varName + "=" + value + ", ";
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    string += varName + "=" + "{Unavailable}, ";
}
```

may fail if your field is `null`, you should exploit the `String + operator` to avoid it like this :

```
string += varName + "=" + field.get(object) + ", ";
```

`string` is really a bad name for your variable, maybe rename it as `res` or something ?

I'm no big fan of the printStackTrace, you should consider using the various logging utilities proposed by java : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html or slf4j.

I think those 4 modifications will already make the code neater but we can do a bigger refactoring :
instead of using a String that we concatenate bit by bit and then remove the final comma, you should consider using a `Stream` over the fields array and generating the result with the `Collectors#joining` method.

In the end, you'd have the following method :

```
private static final String SEPARATOR = ", ";

public static String format(Object object) {
    final String className = object.getClass().getSimpleName();
    final String prefix = className + "[";
    String res = Arrays.stream(FieldUtils.getFieldsWithAnnotation(object.getClass(), Formatted.class))
        .map(field -> {
        String varName = field.getName();
        try {
            return varName + "=" + field.get(object);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            log.severe(e.toString());
            return varName + "=" + "{Unavailable}";
        }
    }).collect(joining(SEPARATOR));
    return prefix + res + "]";
}
```